# Long text area not able to save

Tags: community, long-text-area

I have one field with long text area datatype with limit 1000. During the input, I am using JEasyCounter to validate 1000 character. The user insert 1000 character including new line (Of course creating new line is not counted as character) and it prompt this error.

> Upsert failed. First exception on row 0 with id aKMn0000000000asGAA;
>   first error: STRING_TOO_LONG

I notice it read somewhere in the error description. However when I remove new line, just type 1000 character then it will be saved successfully.

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of the [Text Area (long)](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_types.htm):

> Note that every time you press Enter within a long text area field, a
>   linebreak and a return character are added to the text. These two
>   characters count toward the 131,072 character limit.

So you should somehow cut out these characters: [`\r`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_carriagereturn.asp)and [`\n`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_newline.asp)

Comment: can it be done in javascript side?i m not sure jeasycounter able to catch this.i need to research more.

Comment: @unidha Of course it could be done with javascript. BUT you need to implement a double check: JS and Apex.